# Show ROUND AVG function using php

Tags: php, mysql, average, rounding

Hello I want some help to learn how to show the average function using php, I got an error when I fetch the array, it shows something like this
 **Undefined index: ROUND (AVG(encuestas.respuestas),2)** .
Thanks in advance

```
$objdat = new Database();

//function to show the average
$query= "SELECT areas_evaluacion.nombre_area,AVG(encuestas.respuestas) AS promedio
FROM encuestas

INNER JOIN areas_evaluacion on areas_evaluacion.id = encuestas.id_area_evaluacion

group by encuestas.id_area_evaluacion";
$get_var =$objdat ->select($query);

<?php while($r=mysql_fetch_array($get_var)){

echo $r['promedio'];
 }
```

Comment: Alias your `ROUND (AVG(encuestas.respuestas),2)` in the SQL query, then reference it by that alias in your `$row` array.... it's so much easier

Comment: `var_dump($r)` to see what's really in the array.

Comment: I edit the code as you suggest but It still showing an error

Comment: @MarcB  it shows these  array(4) { [0]=> string(8) "Limpieza" ["nombre_area"]=> string(8) "Limpieza" [1]=> string(5) "58.33" ["promedio"]=> string(5) "58.33" } array(4) { [0]=> string(19) "Mobiliario y equipo" ["nombre_area"]=> string(19) "Mobiliario y equipo" [1]=> string(6) "100.00" ["promedio"]=> string(6) "100.00" }

Comment: so there you go. you've got `AS promedio` in your query, so your AVG() is showing up as `promedio` in the results... PHP would only ever see the aliased name, never the original expression that got aliased.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks it works,  I change  `echo $r['promedio'];`